# Where is the default tesseract installation folder on a mac?

Tags: macos, tesseract

I've just installed tesseract through homebrew, I need to put some files inside the tessdata folder but I can't find it anywhere on my mac.

I searched for "tesseract" in the finder and the search returned nothing, I couldn't find anything on google either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you installed it through brew, try running `brew list tesseract`

In my case it gave out the following locations:

```
MBP-2:/ joantune$ brew list tesseract
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/bin/tesseract
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/include/tesseract/ (27 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/lib/ (2 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/share/man/ (11 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/share/tessdata/ (27 files)
```

Port and others should have similar commands.

You can always go on the terminal and `cd / && sudo find . -iname tesseract`

Comment: If using MacPorts use:
port contents tesseract