# (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file') on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-tesseract

I am trying to run Tesseract into Google Colab:

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
!pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract
import shutil
import os
import random
try:
 from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
 import Image

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('aaa.png'))
print(extractedInformation)
```

I tried running on an image ('aaa.png') I am uploading, but it runs this error:

```
TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')
```

Searching from an almost identical (still unsolved) post, I tried the following code, but still is not working:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (
    r'/usr/local/bin/tesseract'
)
```

I tried to access the pytesseract folder, but it runs this error:

[image]

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py'
```

Comment: you missed `str` in front of `pytesseract.image_to_string`

Comment: do you mean pytesseract.image_to_string(str...? I googled but every code has the same line I used

Comment: No. try `str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('aaa.png')))`

Comment: Unfortunately same exact problem, I also tried running without the line _cmd, same issue

Comment: you definitely need that `cmd` - where did you save that cmd? if you are on Mac, it's usually under `r'/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/your tesseract verison/bin/tesseract'`

Comment: see here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812839/where-is-the-default-tesseract-installation-folder-on-a-mac)

Comment: I am using Google Collaboratory notebook. I added details in the main question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (
    r'/usr/bin/tesseract'
)
```